# onSizeChanged() is called multiple times with slightly different Y values, corresponding to notification bar height

Tags: android, android-view

I have a custom `ViewGroup` whose `onSizeChanged()` is overridden to allow me to determine the overall size of the entire `View` hierarchy. So far I had assumed that, as long as the passed parameters aren't zero, then the dimensions given are definitive dimensions for the `View`. For information, the `ViewGroup` fills almost the entire screen, with only an `ActionBar` and notification bar at the top.

What I have found is that, sometimes, `onSizeChanged()` will be called more than once in succession, with values for Y that differ by 50. I *think* this is happening after a configuration change (i.e. a device rotation). On my device, 50px corresponds with the height of the top notification bar. In landscape orientation I have used `FLAG_FULLSCREEN` to hide the top notification bar, so what I am speculating here is that, when the device is rotated and the `View` is restored from saved state, perhaps it passes the `View` hierarchy through several measure/layout phases due to the timing of the OS removing or replacing the notification bar.

Would I be right in my assessment, and is there a way I can ensure that the values I obtain via `onSizeChanged()` are the definitive ones?

Although I realise that given several calls to `onSizeChanged()` the final set of values will be the 'correct' ones, due to the nature of my application I must know when the values received are the 'correct' steady-state dimensions of the `View`. So far, the best way I can think of to solve this is to use a somewhat crude delayed process that checks the dimensions after a period of time.

Comment: I have the same problem. I think you may be right about the OS recalculating after  removing or adding nav bar. I am try to see how many times the size method is called